# Call a function or view with a parameter

Tags: sql, windows, postgresql

I want to create function or view which will show some information particular year monthly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW name_view AS 
    SELECT d_name,
    SUM("Jan") "Jan",
    SUM("Feb") "Feb"
    ...
    FROM (
    select distinct d_name,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM h_date) = '01' THEN query_string ELSE NULL END) "Jan",
      COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM h_date) = '02' THEN query_string ELSE NULL END) "Feb",
    ..
       from h
           inner join d on h_d = d_id
                WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM h_date) = '2015' 
            GROUP BY  d_name) sub query
    GROUP BY d_name
```

How can I call view like this without

> WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM h_date) = '2015'

but with the year of the call? For example

> SELECT * FROM name_view ('2015')

Comment: Create a function that returns a table.

Comment: you should create a stored procedure instead@@"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use YEAR in the SELECT and when you SELECT from the view you use WHERE year = 2015.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW name_view AS 
SELECT d_name,
SUM("Jan") "Jan",
SUM("Feb") "Feb",
YEAR,
....
```

Use of view:

```
SELECT * 
FROM name_view 
WHERE year = '2015';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function passing date as a parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "show_info"("DATE" date)
  RETURNS SETOF show_info AS
$BODY$SELECT d_name,
    SUM("Jan") "Jan",
    SUM("Feb") "Feb"
    ...
    FROM (
    select distinct d_name,
      COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM h_date) = '01' THEN query_string ELSE NULL END) "Jan",
      COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT (MONTH FROM h_date) = '02' THEN query_string ELSE NULL END) "Feb",
    ..
       from h
           inner join d on h_d = d_id
                WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM h_date) = $1 
            GROUP BY  d_name) subquery
    GROUP BY d_name
;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

You can call it like

```
select * from show_info(date)
```

here date will be whatever date you want to pass

Comment: This function would fail, "SHOW_INFO" and "show_info" aren't the same. Advice: Don't use double quotes " and don't use UPPER CASE characters for object names like function names.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I edited my answer. I removed double quotes and changed the function name in lower case letters. Thanks for correction :)